# Best way to count nest depth in e.g. f[f[f[...[f[x]]...]?

Tags: iteration

What is the best way to count nesting depth in e.g. `f[f[f[...[f[x]]...]`? In other words, what function `func` is good for giving you something more or less like the following:

```
func[Nest[f, h[x], n], f] == n
```

To be clear, the goal is to specifically count the nesting depth of only one function head (here, `f`), so `f[f[h[f[x]]]]` should return `3`.

Comment: `Depth[#] - 1 & @ Nest[f, x, 7]`?

Comment: @Trev kglr was answering the question you asked... Please add that case from your comment to the question, and any other cases you would like handled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You can get a very fast, and very general (avoiding `$RecursionLimit`) function by looking for the first position (of the right kind) at which the nesting *stops*, instead of directly counting how many nestings have occurred.

**EDIT:** *However, inspired by MichaelE2's* `ArrayDepth` *answer,*

```
hdepth[expr_, f_] :=
 Replace[
  Dimensions[expr, AllowedHeads -> f],
  {x : Longest[1 ...], ___} :> Length[{x}]]
```

*seems to be even faster, just as robust, and a lot more readable. But if you'd like to see how looking for an exception to the nesting chain works, read on...*

---

While both nice, there are two potential problems with the existing answers: @mikado's nice and clean functional solution will potentially hit `$RecursionLimit` on very deeply nested `f`-expressions, e.g. `Nest[f, x, 2000]`, and (as of the time of writing) @kglr's clever identification of `Position` as a useful tool here only coincides with the "nest depth" in special cases. In general, it gets the depth of the deepest occurrence of `f` anywhere in the expression; consider `f[h[f[x]]]`.

One option to circumvent the recursion limit is to use `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) instead of function definitions. There are several ways to make this work, but I tested with

```
t = Nest[f, x, 50000];
```

which quickly led to 30-second computation times. I moved `Position`, but only managed to cut the time in half.

So, here's the trick, using `Position`, that works quickly:

- Check that the expression is of the form `f[_]`
- If so, look for the positions of `f[patt]` where `patt` matches any sequence of arguments that *isn't* of the form `f[_]`
- Take only the positions "on the main branch", i.e. of the form `{1, 1, 1, ...}`; get their length, and add 1.

For `patt`, we need to account for the fact that `Except` can't handle variable-length patterns. So I took `patt` to be `Except[f[_]] | Repeated[_, {0}] | Repeated[_, {2, Infinity}]`, as I found it to be the fastest among the ones I tried.

```
hdepth[f_][expr : f_[_]] := 
 1 + Min[
  Cases[
   Position[expr, 
    f[Except[f[_]] | Repeated[_, {0}] | Repeated[_, {2, Infinity}]]],
     x : {1 ...} :> Length[x]]]

hdepth[f_][Except[f_[_]]] := 0
```

I use two definitions to check that the expression matches `f[_]`, but you could bundle this in a single definition if you want to.

This cuts a 30-second evaluation time down to 0.01 seconds.

```
hdepth[f][t] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.01049995313, 50000} *)
```

Hope this helps; let me know if it misjudges the depth in any case! :)

---

Here are some tests and pathological cases I could think of; note that since `Nest` does not have `SequenceHold`, and thus splices `Sequence[...]` arguments into its argument sequence, we don't consider `f[x,y]` or `f[]` to be a once-nested instance of `f`.

```
hdepth[f][x]           (* 0 *)

hdepth[f][f[x]]        (* 1 *)

hdepth[f][f[h[f[x]]]]  (* 1 *)

hdepth[f][f[x][x]]     (* 0 *)

hdepth[f][f[x, y]]     (* 0 *)

hdepth[f][f[]]         (* 0 *)
```

Note that, admittedly, `50000` is about the most I could `Nest` `f` on my computer before crashing the kernel—but I chose this arbitrarily, so I didn't realize until after :)

---

For fun, here are two that worked, but weren't so fast (despite being the fastest I could find of their "class").

```
(* Get all "main branch" positions of f[_], then see how many 
   appear consecutively: *)

hdepth2[expr_, f_] := Catch[Fold[If[#1 === #2, #1 + 1, Throw[#1]] &, 0, 
  Sort[Cases[Position[expr, f[_]], x : {1 ...} :> Length[x]]]]]
```

```
(* Use a module wrapper to prevent accidental matches with //., 
   since //. acts on all parts of the expression *)

hdepth3[expr_, f_] := 
 Module[{w}, (w[expr,0] //. w[f[x_], n_] :> w[x, n + 1]) // Last]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can define a simple function to do this:

```
fdepth[f[u_]] := 1 + fdepth[u]
fdepth[_] = 0;
```

For example

```
NestList[f, h[g[x]], 5]
(* {h[g[x]], f[h[g[x]]], f[f[h[g[x]]]], f[f[f[h[g[x]]]]], 
 f[f[f[f[h[g[x]]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[h[g[x]]]]]]]} *)

fdepth /@ %
(* {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html):

```
ClearAll[nestDepth]
nestDepth[func_] := Max @* Map[Length] @* Position[func] 

nestDepth[f] @ Nest[f, w @ g @ h @ x, 8]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

```
nestDepth[f] /@ NestList[f, w @ g @ h @ x, 5]
```

> ```
> {-∞, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

You can also use [`Count`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[nestDepth2]
nestDepth2[func_] := Count[#, Blank @ func, All] &

nestDepth2[f] @ Nest[f, w @ g @ h @ x, 8]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

```
nestDepth2[f] /@ NestList[f, w @ g @ h @ x, 5]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `ArrayDepth`?

```
ArrayDepth[f[f[f[h[x]]]]]
(*  3  *)

ArrayDepth@Nest[f, x, 7]
(*  7  *)
```

`ArrayDepth` has an `AllowedHeads` option, which is not needed on the OP's example.

Comment: There is one situation where that doesn't capture the number of times `f` has been nested (on a non-`f`-headed expression): in situations like `f[f[x], f[x]]`, which has an `ArrayDepth` of `2` but a "nested depth" of 0. In the same vein, perhaps `LengthWhile[Dimensions[t, AllowedHeads -> f], # === 1 &]` would work? this is just about as fast as my answer, which is nice!

Comment: @thorimur Thanks. It might depend on the definition of "nested function." Think nested lists:  `{1, {2}}` is often called a nested list. I was concerned rather that `f[y, f[x]]` might be considered to have a nested depth of 2, instead of 1 as `ArrayDepth` will return. Hence the remark at the end of my answer. All that aside, I think `ArrayDepth` is the easiest way to solve the problem the OP presented.

Comment: good point! it's true that the desired behavior is ambiguous; I think I assumed from the presence of `Nest` in the example that the goal was primarily to "count the number of applications of `f`" in the kind of expressions produced by `Nest`, but you're right, that's not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting answers, I kind of figured there'd be a simpler built-in method for this.

Here's another workable low-tech approach:

```
fDepth[expr_, f_] := StringCount[ToString@expr, ToString@f <> "["]
```

This seems to take about 3x the time of thorimur's answer, but it is drop-dead simple.

Note that without some safeguards, this approach would fail in any context where you have the function `f` alongside other functions ending with `f`.